# Video intended for background does not play

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I want to put on my application a background video on the login/register page

I have made videobg.xml layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/bgVideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

after that I made videologreg.java

```java
public class videologreg extends AppCompatActivity {
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //to play a video on the login background
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.bgVideoView);



        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.asf);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.start();

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer -> mediaPlayer.setLooping(true));




    }
}
```

and finally I'm in the register login layout

```xml
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/videopozadina" />
```

however the video does not play at all so I would like your help, thanks in advance.

I have tried all the above things but unfortunately it doesn't work

About black screen what i got

[image: what i got]

Comment: Can you provide more information on this statement ***however the video does not play at all***? Any error log? And do you test it on an emulator? Can you try it on a real device or try another emulator? And also what is your ```R.raw.asf``` format? Is the encoding supported by the device?

Comment: Hello! Sure i have tried both emulator and Real device. R.raw.asf it's MP4 file so yes supported by device. Log is clear.

Comment: May I know if you are showing the correct layout with ```@layout/videopozadina```? The way that you set the video to your ```VideoView``` looks good to me. And just to double confirm your video can be played and is not corrupted?

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. I have tried with another video but same thing... Also i have tried to add directly to my fragment_login layour by
`<VideoView
            android:id="@+id/bgVideoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:keepScreenOn="true" />
`
Still no progress...

Comment: I have instead provided a little guiding sample that should be working fine. See if it gives you any hint.

Comment: I have reposted another guide from your provided screenshot. See if that is your case?

Answer (score 0):

So from the provided screenshot, I guess it should be from this xml:

```xml
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/videopozadina" />
    <!-- There should be more layout design here -->
```

And you need to make sure that for this layout `videopozadina`, it has the `VideoView` defined there, which I believe it should be something you provided like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/bgVideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, you need to further define an ID for the included layout in the first xml mentioned here:

```xml
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include id="@+id/videoLayout" 
             layout="@layout/videopozadina" />
   <!-- There should be more layout design here -->
```

And you should set the video in the Fragment or Activity of your login / register page (I am not sure if it is `videologreg`):

```java
public class videologreg extends AppCompatActivity {
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // I guess you should have setContentView() elsewhere, and the View should be the first mentioned xml, I believe
        // to play a video on the login background
        // You should first retrieve the included layout with the ID first, then further access the VideoView inside the included layout
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoLayout).findViewById(R.id.bgVideoView);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.asf);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.start();
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer -> mediaPlayer.setLooping(true));
    }
}
```